# How do I find a directory on a system no matter where it is in python?

Tags: python, glob

I have a series of scripts running for an automation project. One of the scripts creates a folder called "cloned_git_repo". The next script needs to look in that folder for the files to run conversions on. How can I get my Python script to automatically get to that folder to work from?
This is the code:

```
result = [y for x in os.walk('/Users/user.name/Desktop/automation_project/cloned_git_repo') for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.csv'))]
```

Instead of hardcoding that directory path, how can I have it automatically get to the 'cloned_git_repo' and continue the rest of the program. It can't be hardcoded because different people on different machines will be running the script so '/Users/user.name/Desktop/automation_project/cloned_git_repo' will be different per machine. Thanks!

Comment: Add a config file to your project that stores the path to the files your project needs.  Then just read in that file or prompt the user to select the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is to access an environment variable, e.g. `$HOME` and your script would take over from that. This would be somewhat *above* Python (any script could do that).

In Python, you could use:

```
import os


HOME = os.getenv('HOME')
```

to get it.

A cleaner (and cross-platform) approach would be to use [`os.path.expanduser()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.expanduser), e.g.:

```
import os


HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
```

In both case, you should get the `/Users/user.name` part of the path in `HOME`, and you can take it from there.

For example:

```
result = [
    y
    for x in os.walk('/Users/user.name/Desktop/automation_project/cloned_git_repo')
    for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.csv'))]
```

could become:

```
import os


HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
result = [
    y
    for x in os.walk(os.path.join(HOME, 'Desktop/automation_project/cloned_git_repo'))
    for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.csv'))]
```

---

A more flexible approach would be to use a higher level package, e.g. [`appdir`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/), which offers cross-platform methods for accessing a variety of standard paths.